# How to call arbitrary method as Any type with argument list of Any*?

Tags: scala

How would I implement the following method in Scala, given that *method* is a function that can take the amount of arguments in *arguments*?

```
def applyAny(method: Any, arguments: Any*) = ???
```

My intended use for this is in combination with [scala.Dynamic](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic), like so:

```
val dynamicValue: Dynamic
dynamicValue.myAdd = (x,y) = > x + y
dynamicValue.myAdd(2,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it from your example snippet that you intend these "methods" to be one of the 23 `FunctionN` types.

In that case, there is not much you can do but to use runtime dispatch on said 23 types:

```
def applyAny(method: Any, arguments: Any*): Any = (arguments.size, method) match {
  case (0, f: Function0[_]) =>
    f()
  case (1, f: Function1[_, _]) =>
    f.asInstanceOf[Function1[Any, Any]](arguments(0))
  case (2, f: Function2[_, _, _]) =>
    f.asInstanceOf[Function2[Any, Any, Any]](arguments(0), arguments(1))
  ...
  case (22, f: Function22[_, _, ..., _]) =>
    f.asInstanceOf[Function22[Any, Any, ..., Any]](arguments(0), arguments(1), ..., arguments(21))
  case _ =>
    sys.error("Arity mismatch")
}
```

Not pretty, and lots of opportunities for `ClassCastException`s at runtime in various places.

Comment: Your 'take' is correct. Why do you expect the ClassCastException?

Comment: Well, if you do anything wrong, say call a method expecting an `Int` but giving it a `String` instead, the type system won't be able to help you, and you'll get `ClassCastException`s at runtime.